# Implements Serialization in VO without saving the state of Object?

Tags: java, serialization

Currently in the project few VO's(value objects) class are being serialized by implementing Serializable interface. this class has nothing more then getters and setters.
No where further in the code they are doing writeObject or saving the object state.

Is there any value to make my VO Serializable makes any sense ??

Comment: It all depends on how and where you use it (It can be used in DnD in Swing application, but also EJB within a JEE application), please specify your context. You don't need to override writeObject and readObject to make an object "Serializable".

Comment: hi, this is a JEE application but we do not send this VO object over the network. this VO acts within a small context to communicate data from class to class.  But what i want to understand here is,if i wont override the method where will the objects state will be saved?? and its uses if i wont write it to specific file.

Comment: Everything that is stored in a non-transient/non-static field will be serialized/deserialized automatically.

Comment: Got the Answer, In our scenario the servers are under the clustered environment. during any fail of Server A, now the Server B will clone the same session so nothing will be lost. For this process to persist the state of VO we need to make it as implements Serializable.

Thanks for other answers too..

Thanks
Punith

Answer (score 0):

Let's argue with a simple case : Imagine an Entity wrapping some value objects and you want to manage your entity with for instance Hibernate framework.

Hibernate may need serializable class :

> The class should implement Serializable. Strictly speaking, this is
>   not a requirement. However, in practice you will normally want your
>   Hibernate objects to be serializable so that they can be (potentially)
>   migrated around a multiprocessor cluster or saved and restored across
>   a web server reboot etc.

Of course, you don't have to precise writeObject and readObject method because default serialization use reflection to save and restore object states.

Actually, those methods are interesting when you want to customize serialization, like for instance initialize a field (present in client class but not existing within server class) during deserialization with a precised default value.